# Domino eulerian path problem

Tags: terminology, eulerian-path

I'm looking at an example of an eulerian path problem, and it's not clear to me what the problem is.

> There are N dominoes, as it is known, on both ends of the Domino one number is written(usually from 1 to 6, but in our case it is not important). You want to put all the dominoes in a row so that the numbers on any two adjacent dominoes, written on their common side, coincide. Dominoes are allowed to turn.

What does it mean for "numbers on any 2 adjacent dominoes, written on their common side, coincide?"

Are the dominoes laying flat, like this:
[image]

Or are the dominoes standing up? That part wasn't clear. If it's the latter, then that makes more sense. If it's the former, then the question seems moot.

This is a question from https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/euler_path.html#toc-tgt-1

Comment: I believe they are lying flat. Why does that make the question moot. What is the question anyway? What book is the quotation from? the number of spots usually runs from 0 to 6 (not from 1 to 6). For the standard "double six" domino set (N - 28) Eulerian paths exist (they are actually Eulerian cycles), counting them is a nice exercise in combinatorics.

Comment: I meant that if are standing up, then the question seems a bit moot. If they're standing up, I assume that two adjacent dominoes must have the same number of dots on each end, so that means all the dominoes must be identical. The original problem is on https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/euler_path.html#toc-tgt-1 under the heading "The Domino Problem"

Comment: I think you should put that reference and link in the question. Note that the set of dominoes can be thought of as a graph; the domino with 5 spots on one end and 1 spot on the other end is an edge joining vertex 5 and vertex 1; a domino with the same number of spots on each end is a self-loop.

Comment: You play dominos by laying them flat, not by standing them up.

Comment: @bof Yes. I understand the graph representation. It seems to determine whether this is doable, we just need to check (1) The graph is connected (2) Each node has an even number of degrees? It's not clear to me why this guarantees an Eulerian path.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ahh. I never played dominioes :)

Comment: @24n8:  There is a theorem that says that is all you have to check on a graph to make sure there is a Eulerean circuit (not just path).  The intuitive proof is that you start from somewhere and each time you visit a vertex uses two connections, one in and one out.  If all vertices are even you can't get stuck.

Comment: @RossMillikan When I think about it like that, it makes sense (I just need to remember that the graph needs to be connected). But, for this problem, I'm not sure if it's an actual Eulerian path because the problem statement doesn't seem to constrain the dominoes to form a loop of any sort. They could simply just lie in a single row like in the picture in the OP? In that case 2 of the numbers will have exact 1 degree?

Comment: @24n8:  As there is symmetry between the numbers, if most of them have an even number of squares, all of them will.  That means the ends will match and you have a circuit.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hmmm what if you have the following set of dominoes: [2,3],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]. Here 2,4,5 have an even number of degrees, but 3,6 do not.

Comment: To me a set of dominoes has all pairs from $0$ up to some number, most often $6$ or $9$.  I note that the question did not specify the symmetry.  Then the same theorem says there is an Eulerean path if only two vertices are odd, but you must start from one and end at the other.  You are expected to use this.